# Intellij git bash terminal tilde key

Tags: intellij-idea, terminal, git-bash

I set git-bash for windows as default terminal in Intellij IDEA. It works but I am unable to write tilde (`~`) character there (`Shift`+`~`). Tried changing different options in settings but without any luck.

versions: 
Windows 10
Intellij IDEA 2017.2.5
git version 2.14.2.windows.3
path to shell: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`

Does anyone had similar problem and know the solution?

It is really annoying when I have to copy this character or work in seperate terminal in situation where direct view on code is preferable.

Comment: the closest jetbrains ticket is https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152703 always open in 2020

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really a solution, but probably a more convenient workaround: you can use `ALT` + `126` to print tilde character.

(while keep press `Alt`, on your keyboard type the number `126`).

Comment: As far as I can see intellij shortcuts are called even with focus in embedded terminal (despite checking option "override IDEe shortcuts") so can't check it.

Comment: Ah, tried with numpad and it actually works. Not a solution but I can take that.

Comment: I am joining in pain with all forced Windows users :-(

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue.
I accidentally clicked on 'F6' today and this added ~ in my console. 
It isn't resolve, but I guess that easier workaround.

Comment: Somehow it started to work but don't really know what was the problem and which action served as solution. Just want to say that it is possible to handle it somehow.

Comment: When i type F6 it just inserts "Function Key 6" in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by enabling the keyboard type called eliminate dead keys. In my case it is Swedish and the keyboard type on Linux Elementary OS I'm using is called `Swedish (eliminate dead keys)`.

It is available in other languages as well including Norwegian and German.

The disadvantage is that you cannot combine these to make characters anymore.

Comment: what do you mean saying "The disadvantage is that you cannot combine these to make characters anymore." ?

Comment: @jareeq I'm not sure if you are familiar with using a Swedish keyboard and I know very little of other keyboard languages. However normally I can type ´+e to form é. With the setting selected above this feature is gone. Not a very big problem since e´ can be used instead, other character like ü and õ will not be possible though.

Comment: try up vote this issue to get chance that it will be done:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152703

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the solution nor given in other answers work for me, so I will just share workaround I use. It's ugly, but better than copying tilde from other Window.

In *~/.bashrc* file I added `alias T='echo ~'` (and invoked `source ~/.bashrc` after, to apply changes) so now everytime I need tilde I use `$(T)`, for example `ls $(T)`.

As other said upvoting this problem in youtrack may bring solution sooner or later - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-152703